# redirect to login page when user press logout in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem when user clicks on logout, he's getting redirected to wordpress's login page, whereas I want him to be redirected to website's login page.

Here's the header link I'm trying, but it's not working :

```
header("Location:http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/ngo/wp-login.php?action=logout".
           "&redirect_to=http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/ngo/?page_id=56");

get_header();
```

`ngo/?page_id=56` is the permalink to the login page.

Comment: Why not just to `header("Location: http://.../ngo?page_id=56");` ?

Comment: no because it has to be logged off, if i just do that it'll redirect me to login page but it'll not actually log out !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the WP [function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url) for that purpose. The parameter is the URL to redirect to on logout. :

```
<?php echo wp_logout_url( $redirect ); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'my_redirect' );

function my_redirect() {
    wp_redirect( 'http://whatever_you_like.com' );
}
```

WordPress has a hook system where you can hook to most significant moments. With the code above we simply say we want to handle something on log out and where is our handler callback.

I can give you also OOP style, if you have class.

Comment: it's not working, it's not even redirecting me to login page...
Is wp_logout a function ??

Comment: I have tested it. It was working for me. Where you placed the code?
Yes it is a function and we hook it.

Comment: I have placed that code in my logout.php file..
Is wp_logout a inbuilt wordpress function ??

Comment: You can add it in a theme or plugin. Yes it is WordPress function.

Comment: Ok, I am using profile-builder plugin for profile-login-logout-lostpassword.
I have placed my logout.php in themes.
I am using SwirlsAndSpirals theme.

Comment: I haven't used that theme exactly, but I suppose it has functions.php - add it there.